# Circuitikz how to draw diodes against each other

Tags: circuitikz

I want to draw some diodes in series to the bulk of a mosfet but the diodes should point against each other. I tried the following but it does not really yield in a clean result. There must be a better way!

```
\begin{circuitikz} 
        \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.8, 
            capacitors/scale=0.7, 
            diodes/scale=0.6,
            transistors/scale=1.3}
        \draw (4,0) node[pmos, emptycircle, bulk] (pmos) {}
        (pmos.gate) node[anchor=east] {g} 
        (pmos.bulk)+(0.5,0) node[above] {b}
        (pmos.drain) node[anchor=north] {d}
        (pmos.source) node[anchor=south] {s}
        (pmos.bulk) to[D] ++(2,0)
        (pmos.bulk)+(4,0) to[D] (pmos.bulk)+(2,0)
        (pmos.bulk)+(1.5,0) node[above] {tw};
\end{circuitikz}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
For drawing diode in the opposite direction of path is intended option `invert`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
        \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.8,
            capacitors/scale=0.7,
            diodes/scale=0.6,
            transistors/scale=1.3}
\draw   (4,0) node[pmos, emptycircle, bulk] (pmos) {}
        (pmos.gate) node[anchor=east] {g}
        (pmos.bulk)+(0.5,0) node[above] {b}
        (pmos.drain) node[anchor=north] {d}
        (pmos.source) node[anchor=south] {s}
        (pmos.bulk) to[D] ++ (2.0,0)  node[above] {tw}
                    to[D,invert] ++ (1.5,0)
        ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]